# выбор выводимого output в shiny r studio

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

Мне нужно, чтобы при выборе Statistika, выводилось только summary. При выборе Grafy, соответственно, только график.
ui.

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
headerPanel ('Aplikace'),


sidebarPanel(
sliderInput(inputId = 'pocet', label = 'zadej pocet', min = 50, max = 1000, value = 100, step = 10),
sliderInput(inputId = 'mean', label = 'zadej mean', min = 0, max = 300, value = 100, step = 1),
sliderInput(inputId = 'sd', label = 'zadej sd', min = 0, max = 100, value = 100, step = 0.5),
submitButton(text = 'prepoctej', icon = NULL, width = NULL),
selectInput("a", "Vyberte:",
            list("Statistika" = "Statistika", 
                 "Grafy" = "Grafy"))
),
mainPanel(
plotOutput('graf'),
verbatimTextOutput ('popis')

)
)
)
```

server.

```
shinyServer(function (input, output){

nahodne = reactive({
rnorm (input$pocet, input$mean, input$sd)
})

output$graf = renderPlot({
boxplot(nahodne())

})

output$popis = renderPrint({
summary(nahodne())
})
})
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Если просто "или-или" то:

```
shinyServer(function (input, output){  
  nahodne = reactive({
   rnorm (input$pocet, input$mean, input$sd)
  })

  output$graf = renderPlot({
    if (input$a=="Grafy")
    {boxplot(nahodne())}
  })
  output$popis = renderPrint({
    if (input$a=="Statistika")
    {summary(nahodne())}
  })
})
```

Если надо менять при этом и положение на экране, то это делается уже в UI.R